# What is the right code for a number sequence in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a tool to generate a Continuity and Isolation Check.

This is the sequence I would like:

[image]

I'm basically trying to create a sequence on the right side of my table that generates a diminishing pattern. 1 to 5, 2 to 5, 3 to 5 etc.

On the left, every set of numbers will be next to 1, then 2, etc. Like the picture.

Here is my code so far. There is some sequence in here I can't figure out how to create a code for:

```
    Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim i As Integer
   
        
        For i = 1 To 5
        
        Cells(i, 4).Value = i     '' 1 -15 starting after the 15th integer
        Cells(i + 4, 4).Value = i      '' 2 -15 starting after the 15th integer
        Cells(i + 7, 4).Value = i      '' 3 -15 starting after the 15th integer
        Cells(i + 9, 4).Value = i
        Cells(i + 10, 4).Value = i
        
        Next i

End Sub
```

What can I try next?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need 2 nested loops:

```
n = 5
row = 1
for i = 1 to n
    for j = i to n
        if i <> j Then
            cells(row, 1) = i
            cells(row, 2) = j
            row = row + 1
        EndIf
    next
Next
```

Comment: There should be a `row = row + 1` in the inner for loop as well. And the  inner for loop should be `For j = i to n`?

Comment: @RaymondWu Added it immediately after posting. Thanks though.

Comment: @TimWilliams Fixed. Doing this from my mobile :-)

Comment: This is clean, elegant as hell and beautiful thank you. This worked great. The only tweak id need is to delete the rows that have the same number on both rows. where its 1 and 1 and 2 and 2 etc. But i might employ a macro that clears the matching values across the rows or something like that, unless you have a simpler solution?

Comment: You mean that you do not want to include matching rows and remove the row entirely? Or you want to cross them as in the image?

Comment: yes, i want to remove the row entirely. i'm using to create Continuity and Isolation tables to check a cable harness, so there would be no need to test pin 1 to pin 1 on the same connector.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: absolutely brilliant and worked like a charm. Thank you so much. Exactly what I needed. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Array version which is faster than writing to cells repeatedly in the loop:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Test()
    GenerateDiminishingPattern 5
End Sub

Private Sub GenerateDiminishingPattern(argLimit As Long)
    Const startRow As Long = 1
    
    Const repeatCol As Long = 1 'Column A
    Const diminishingCol As Long = 4 'Column D
        
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'Change the sheet name accordingly
       
    '=== Uncomment if you need to apply strikethrough to the first value of each loop
    'ws.Columns(repeatCol).Clear
    'ws.Columns(diminishingCol).Clear
        
    '=== Determine the size for array based on sum of consecutive number
    Dim outputSize As Long
    outputSize = (argLimit * (argLimit + 1)) / 2
    
    Dim repeatOutput() As Long
    Dim diminishingOutput() As Long
    
    ReDim repeatOutput(1 To outputSize, 1 To 1) As Long
    ReDim diminishingOutput(1 To outputSize, 1 To 1) As Long
    
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    
    Dim rowIndex As Long
    rowIndex = 1
    
    For i = 1 To argLimit
    
        '=== Uncomment if you need to apply strikethrough to the first value of each loop
        'ws.Cells(startRow, repeatCol).Offset(rowIndex - 1).Font.Strikethrough = True
        'ws.Cells(startRow, diminishingCol).Offset(rowIndex - 1).Font.Strikethrough = True
        For j = i To argLimit
            repeatOutput(rowIndex, 1) = i
            diminishingOutput(rowIndex, 1) = j
            rowIndex = rowIndex + 1
        Next j
    Next i
    
    'Write output to worksheet
    ws.Cells(startRow, repeatCol).Resize(outputSize).Value = repeatOutput
    ws.Cells(startRow, diminishingCol).Resize(outputSize).Value = diminishingOutput
    
    Erase repeatOutput
    Erase diminishingOutput
    Set ws = Nothing
End Sub
```